# Automatic re-connection to public WiFi hotspot with web-based sign-in?

Tags: wireless-networking, login, automation

There are many public WiFi hotspots that require you to visit a special login page before they let you connect to the Internet. Often they have a time limit after which you have to repeat the login procedure, which can be annoying. Can this process be more or less easily automated on the client side so that login and reconnection happen proactively as soon as connectivity to the Internet is lost, not when a page fails to load for a user?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about connection with tablet or android phone, I use this app.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.uk.syslynx.wifiwebloginapp&hl=en